# Converted bigint to varchar in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, dataset

I have this column `ContactNo` and others like this e-g `FaxNo` etc.

Problem is in MSSQL these columns were defined as bigint, and I changed them to varchar in MSSQL using Management Studio:

[image]

The only reason I want to change it from int to varchar/string so that I can have "0" at start. As in int I can't put "0" in the beginning.

I thought I also need to do change in dataset so I also updated the dataset in WPF. In Data Sets Changed the same column for same table from `System.Int64` to `System.String`

[image]

But even I still get this error:

```
Specified Cast is not valid
```

[image]

It works fine if I change back types to whatever types they were before, but those big int types don't allow zeros.

When I do debugging, see this yellow highlight. After this it directly jumps to exception error:

[image]

### Update 1

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try delete the table modified from the DataSet1.xsd and re-add it.

Comment: As an aside, what is the point of "from a in blah select a" why not just write "blah", it's the same thing.

Comment: Are you sure you want to change the database just to be able to display the numbers with a leading 0? It sounds like that is better done in the GUI when you show the values? Just remember it will be a pain to do things like sorting/filtering based on those numbers if you turn them into strings.

Comment: It totally should be done by the string format instead of formatting database

Comment: @user3690202
There is not much of filtering and sorting, only/mostly filtering with AccountID or combo boxes etc..  Its a little Application.

Comment: @MajkeloDev
Sorry, i didnt got your point? you mean i should not update the datatype in database??

Comment: His point is the same as mine - changing the database to add a 0 at the start is not a good thing to do. In fact, its a very silly thing to do.

Comment: @user3690202
what to do in this situation then??
in mysql and php was the most simplest thing to do. but now as i moved to .Net even changing datatypes is so difficult. xD

However there is a column Branch code for bank account. There is no way of knowing how many zeroes will be in the beginning. i mean in contact No i can concatenate 0 at start to show right. but how to concatenate zeroes with branch code if i have no idea of how much zeroes exist or even if they exist or not.

Comment: For example if You want to have 6 digits long string from int You can do like this: var test = someInt.ToString("000000");

Comment: @Oluwafemi

Deleted and Recreated Dataset AgentAccounts Tablek, Still Same Error..

Comment: @MajkeloDev
Yes, But how to know if user has entered a brach code with 2 zeroes and in DB those zeroes got removed. As there is no way knowing how many digits are there. No specification??

Comment: What source type is your `cmdAgent` expecting and what type is `query`? and have you updated your `AgentAccounts model class`?

Comment: OK, if you need to be able to differentiate between 001234 and 0001234 then you are right, you need to change the type to a string, because it isn't really a number anymore.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on cmb.ItemsSource = query, and tell use what query is at that point. Tell us what AgentAccounts is, put it's code above as well. Then we can help you.

Comment: @Oluwafemi
`cmdAgent` is the name of a combobox, not sure what type it is or it should be?. there is a `var` used with query, as you can see in pic above, not sure of its type also.
What you mean by AgentAccounts Model Class?? There is no Model Class for AgentAccounts i think..

Comment: I meant `cmdAgent.ItemsSource` and on `dc.AgentAccounts` set your cursor on `AgentAccounts` and press `F12` to go to definition and update the `class` hover on `query` debug mode to see the type.

Comment: @Oluwafemi
i hovered over the query and updated the screenshot..
plus also added the screenshot of AgentAccounts when pressed `F12`

Comment: Do the same for AgentAccount. There should be properties to update.

Comment: Not sure sir?? do what same to AgentAccount?

Comment: `this.GetTable<AgentAccount>()` Set cursor on `AgentAccount` and `F12`

Comment: sometimes clean and rebuild fix errors

Comment: and +1 to @Oluwafemi to delete all dbml content and readd the tables. not just one table.

Comment: @SizzlingCode: please ignore anyone telling you to keep a Fax number as `BIGINT`. Phone numbers are not "numbers" as you never do mathematical operations on them or sort them. They are strings and this field should have never been a `BIGINT` in the first place. So you are correct to be changing it. A numeric type for phone numbers not only can't store leading zeroes, but it also can't store extensions or international numbers such as **+1 12 1231 1231**. Also, your last image with `GetTable<AgentAccount>` is useless as it isn't a definition. What is the definition of the `AgentAccount` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

After going through your code extensively, which is not shown here there were two areas that were problematic.

One was data annotations and the other was still casting to longint in the xaml.cs

When changing datatypes like this, it can be very fiddly, and we need to go through every file in the code where that field is being handled.

I'm glad you solved your problem, we all understand the frustration of hitting a brick wall :)

---

It is possible this is being caused by a setting in MSSERVER:

Go to options and **untick** Prevent saving changes that require table recreation. As you may be appearing to change the table in some parts of your project, but the changes are not being saved in database. So there will be a cast exception, as it is looking for a bigint and not a varchar.

[image]

Comment: Changes Do get Save Sir. After the Change is Implemented than i get this specified cast error..

Comment: Sir, my program works with bigint but when i change to nvarchar my program starts giving error.

so this means data type of column do changes. i already have that checked removed "Prevent saving changes",

Comment: something like that. i also changed value in dataset and and agentaccount class had private attributes, so i also changed from long to string there..

`private long _ContactNo;`

Comment: Many Thanks Problem Solved.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you have a field in AgentAccount which you haven't updated to be a string, and it is still an int. As such, the cast is failing. Select AgentAccount in code, hit F12 to jump to the definition, and then update the field to be a string. Then everything should work.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have made changes in the underlying database, all you need to do in your program is regenerate your typed dataset code. That should solve all such issues.

Try this:

Close all the windows and open `Dataset1.xsd` (designer). Do something on the designer surface that forces it to regenerate the code. Most of the times just even moving one of the tables a bit should do the trick; but if it doesn't just right-click and add a dummy adapter, then save then delete it and save again. (The intention is to make it regenerate the auto-generated code again).

Repeat the process for any more typed datasets you might have. (I see one named RMSDatabase2Dataset. xsd in the screenshot).

Finally save everything and do a full rebuild of the project.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to display leading zeroes only in UI, you can use string format for bindings or you can also use converters.
But if you need to save the values with leading zeroes, in Database, then it is better to change the type to varchar.

Secondly, are you using Datasets or LINQ to SQL Classes? The sample code has both it seems, I assume you are getting the data using adapters in DataClassesDataContext.AgentAccount property.

Make sure that the query returns data else you won't be able to get the exception,since there won't be any object to cast.

While doing the same steps in a simple dataset,everything works fine, coz when you modify the Dataset.ContactNo & save the file, it reflects in all the relevant places.

Answer (score 1):

From `DataSet1.xsd` image you have uploaded, `MaxLength` property of `ContactNo` is `-1`.

After Changing `ContactNo` from `System.Int64` to `System.String` you should also change `ContactNo`'s `MaxLength` from `-1` to `30`.

Comment: Already did that.. But that's no use :( Still got the same error.

Comment: you used Linq To Sql classes? Right?